# Undefined variable: category in edit blade

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, edit

I have this in my controller, but it keeps comes our below error in my edit.blade

ErrorException
Undefined variable: category (View:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*
*/
public function __construct()
{

```
}

public function index()
{
    $categories = category::all();
    return view('category.index', [$categories = 'category']);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('category.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    Category::create($request->all());
  

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Category Successfully Created');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $category=category::find($id);
    return view('category.edit', [$categories = 'category']);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);
        
    $category=category::find($id);  
    $category->update();

    return redirect()->route('category.index')
                    ->with('success','Category updated successfully');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

This is my edit.blade

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{$category->name}}" placeholder="Category Name">
```

Comment: Its a typo, It will be `{{$categories->name}}`, also change your controller code to `[$categories = 'category']` to `[$categories => 'category']`, `=` to `=>` its an another typo mistake of your code

Comment: `[$categories = 'category']` - what this does is assign the string `'category'` to the `$category` variable, overwriting the contents you got from the database. I assume you wanted to put the `$category` variable under the `'category'` index.

Comment: @Espresso `[$categories => 'category']` is not valid. It should be the other way around.

Comment: Opps, my bad, it should `['categories' => $categories]` @El_Vanja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your function like this. I assume your model is in all lowercase

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = category::all();
    return view('category.index', ['categories' => $categories]);
}

public function edit($id) 
{
    $category=category::find($id);
    return view('category.edit', ['category' => $category]); 
}
```

which ***categories*** string is your variable on blade file, and ***$categories*** is variable from the controller

And this is example from your index blade file

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <input type="text" name="name"  id="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $category->name }}" placeholder="Category Name">
@endforeach
```

This is for edit blade file

```
<input type="text" name="name"  id="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $category->name }}" placeholder="Category Name">
```